# Migrating from Xerces to new XML parser C++

Tags: c++, xml, multithreading, parsing, oracle-pro-c

The question of faster XML parsing is asked enough number of times, still it is always not very clear as to what to do when we consider performance.

So i have my question here, we have to parse huge number of XML files to generate flat files. Currently the implementation is in xerces using SAX parser. We are validating the XML files and also the files size is not too large. We have multi process implementation using fork.  We are accessing the oracle DB by proC.

Can someone please suggest me to improve the performance of this application by  30%

I am listing the options below

- Use multi threading
- General C++ tuning
- Improve XML parsing
- Improve times to access DB

Memory is not a big constraint but times are to be improved.

Comment: I suggest RapidXML, it is much faster. See [this benchmark](http://pugixml.org/benchmark.html)

Comment: Rusty this application is built on sun C compiler, rapidXML doesn't support solaris 10 Sun C compiler. Can you come to chat, can we discuss on this? The time frame is 2 months